# Java Simple and Single Threading IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading, console, wait, notify

I have a problem in Java about Threading, its with a Single Thread and its about stopping a Thread and continue.

What my Code does: Class MainWindow Creates a Threadreference and in a endloop it starts and stops it.

The Class MyThread starts the Thread. The run method is pretty short and all it does is do:
1. move the mouse to the left side of the screen 
then 
2. move the mouse to the right side of the screen

When i start the program i get instantly a IllegalMonitorStateException and don't know how to fix it.

```
public class MainWindow
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        MyThread mt = new MyThread();
        while(true)
        {
            mt.start();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            mt.wait();
        }
    }
}

public class MyThread implements Runnable 
{
    private Thread th;
    public MyThread() throws Exception
    {
        th = new Thread();
        th.start();
    }
    public void start() throws InterruptedException
    {
        synchronized(this){
        th.wait();
        }
    }
    public void wait()
    {
        synchronized(this){
        th.notifyAll();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: You're doing it all wrong. You can't tell a thread to wait by calling the `Thread#wait()` method. That method does something entirely different.

Comment: Oh ok i see, i think i got it, its just for Multithreading. I used it because i needed to stop the Thread, but i've read that if the Thread is through the run Method it dies too so i couldnt stop it... i have to reread some stuff and try again

Comment: Yes, you'll have to read a bit :) Your run method is btw not used at all, you'll need to pass the `Runnable` to the thread it it's constructor (e.g. `th = new Thread(this);`), just having a thread and a run method in code nearby doesn't work.

Comment: oh yea thanks @zapl :D i was trying out something and recognized it never went into the run method.. now i know :P thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(true)
        {
            mt.start();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            mt.wait();
        }
```

You should not make the running thread runnable. ie) you cannot start the thread which is already running.